# Is it possible to set the value of a dropdownlist to a session variable by using php?

Tags: php

I am trying to store the selected value of an item in my drop down list into a session variable after selecting it and pressing a button to add it to a session variable. My question is,how to display the selected item of dropdownlist on the dropdown list of next page. 
Here is my code:

```
if ($_POST['submit']){
    $_SESSION['selectBox'] = $_POST['select_box_name'];
}

echo "Your most recent selection was: " . $_SESSION['selectBox'] . "<br/>     <br/>";

?>

<form action="seat.php" method="post">
     Pick A Number: <select name="select_box_name">
     <option value=1>One</option>
     <option value=2>Two</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" />
 </form>
```

Here it displays only the value but I want to display on next page containing same dropdown list....

Comment: can you please provide code and what you have tried already

Comment: Sure that is possible. You just have to create the option tag with the corresponding "selected" property. That is shown in the documentation (you _did_ take a look in there, didn't you?) and also in many examples.

Comment: @hina, let us see your code to make the necessary changes. Click the "edit" link below your question and paste your code.

Comment: I recommend phpfiddle, preferably before the question is posted :P

Comment: @arkascha yes i did......

Comment: OK, but you did not follow what is written in there. Have a try using the `selected` property, as written above too: `<option value=1 selected>One</option>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest way to accomplish this is with a ternary:

```
<select name="select_box_name">
    <option value=1 <?php echo ($_SESSION['selectBox'] == 1) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>One</option>
    <option value=2 <?php echo ($_SESSION['selectBox'] == 2) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Two</option>
</select>
```

Same thing using short open tags:

```
<select name="select_box_name">
    <option value=1 <?=($_SESSION['selectBox'] == 1) ? 'selected' : ''?>>One</option>
    <option value=2 <?=($_SESSION['selectBox'] == 2) ? 'selected' : ''?>>Two</option>
</select>
```

This is easily extended to work within a loop of multiple `<option>`s.

Comment: If it worked @hina, press the green check mark to the left of his answer to mark it as accepted.